# Borders of dragging

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to make my sprites stay in screen borders using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
[self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];
return TRUE; }

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {       

CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
if (selSprite) {
CGPoint oldLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
oldLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldLocation];
oldLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldLocation];

CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldLocation);    
CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
selSprite.position = newPos;     }   }
```

I understand that I need to add some code to specify borders. Something like the following:

```
    int width=point.x;
    int height=point.y;
    if (winSize.width-sprite.contentSize.width/2<width) {
        width=winSize.width-sprite.contentSize.width/2;}
    if (winSize.height-sprite.contentSize.height/2<height) {
        height=winSize.height-sprite.contentSize.height/2;}
    if (sprite.contentSize.height/2>height) {
        height=sprite.contentSize.height/2;}                                                    
    if (sprite.contentSize.width/2>width) {
        width=sprite.contentSize.width/2;}
```

But I'm new to `objective C` and I do not fully understand how to deal with it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!
just add in `if (selSprite) {}` this part of code

```
    int width=touchLocation.x;
    int height=touchLocation.y;
    if (selSprite.contentSize.width!=width) {
        width=selSprite.contentSize.width/2;}
  if (selSprite.contentSize.height/2<height) {
        height=selSprite.contentSize.height/2;}
    [selSprite setPosition:ccp(width,height)];
```